# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{1}f_n(x) e^{-x^2}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n(x)=nxe^{-\sqrt{n}x}$ for $x \in [0,+\infty)$.
The sequence of functions pointwise converges in $x \in [0,+\infty)$ to the null function but not uniformly.
There is uniformly convergence in sub-interval $[a,+\infty)$ with a>0.
To calculate the limit I can't said $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)e^{-x^2} dx$=$ \int_{0}^{1}\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)e^{-x^2} dx$?

Comment: i have correct the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$
I_n = n\int_0^1 xe^{-\sqrt{n}x}e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx.$$ Make change of variable $u=\sqrt{n}x$ to obtain
$$\begin{align*}
I_n =\int_0^\sqrt{n} ue^{-u}e^{-\frac{u^2}n} \mathrm du=\int_0^\infty ue^{-u}e^{-\frac{u^2}n}1_{\{u\le \sqrt{n}\}} \mathrm du.
\end{align*}$$ Then we find that
$$
0\le e^{-\frac{u^2}n}1_{\{u\le \sqrt{n}\}} \le e^{-\frac{u^2}{n+1}}1_{\{u\le \sqrt{n+1}\}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1.
$$ Thus by monotone convergence theorem, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty ue^{-u}e^{-\frac{u^2}n}1_{\{u\le \sqrt{n}\}} \mathrm du\\
&=\int_0^\infty ue^{-u}\mathrm du=\left[-ue^{-u}\right]^\infty_0+\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\mathrm du\\
&=1.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can explicitly evaluate the integral:

$$\int_c^d xe^{-ax}dx = -\left.\frac{1}{a}xe^{-ax}\right|_c^d+\int_c^d\frac{1}{a}
e^{-ax}dx=...$$